# how to compare two string if last two character not matches then return those character

Tags: php, codeigniter

1.I have two string 1.abc and 2.abc_1 and i am comparing these two string 2nd string has two extra character, after comparing how to return these character in php.
2.If the string not ends with "_1" i want to add "_1" if the string ends with "_1 or (any numeric value)" i want to add +1 to that value,how to do this in php.

```
$jobref='abc';
$newjobref='abc_1';
if(strcasecmp($jobref,$newjobref)==0)
{
  //here i want to add _1 to that string
 }
else
{
  //return last two character
  if(last character == (any numeric value))
  {
    //add plus 1 to that value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you do is use `explode` to return the final value of the string, then you can edit that value in the `if`/`else` loop and make `finalblow` the final outcome.

This took about 6 minutes of time to read, research and complete, it's untested but I think what you need to do is break your question into parts and then research individual parts down to solve the question.

Any issues let me know :)

```
$blowref = "abc";
$newblowref = "abc_1";

if(strcasecmp($blowref,$newblowref)==0)
{
  $finalblow = $blowref."_1";
 }
else
{
  //return last two character
    $bog = explode("_",$blowref);
    $bog = end($bog); //the final part of the string after the `_` character
  if(is_numeric($bog) || $bog === 0)
  {
    $finalblow = str_replace($bog,($bog+1),$blowref);
  }
}
```

With thanks/nod to **skh** for the explode concept.

Comment: nope doing some corrections based on my recruitments

Answer (score 2):

If the string doesnt contain an underscore add the _1, if it contains it, `explode` on it, increment and `implode`? Exploding will guarantee a full number.